# TypeORM, ManyToMany Get posts by category id (TreeEntity materialized-path)

Tags: typescript, query-builder, typeorm

I'm trying to get posts by category like a CMS does.

For example query post by categorie A will include all posts attached to Categorie A and also post attached to child of Categorie A.

I really don't know how to build this query, so any help would be greatly appreciated :) .

Here is my entities:

```
@Tree("materialized-path")
export class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;


    @ManyToMany((type) => Post, (post) => post.categories)
    posts: Post[];

    @Expose()
    @TreeChildren()
    children: Category[];

    @Expose()
    @TreeParent()
    parent: Category;
}
```

```
export class Post{
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @ManyToMany((type) => Category, (category) => category.posts)
    @JoinTable()
    categories: Category[];
}
```

Followings SQL Query do the job(Example with category id 1)

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE id IN (
    SELECT postId FROM post_categories_category as postCat WHERE postCat.categoryId IN (
       SELECT id FROM category WHERE category.mpath LIKE "1.%" OR category.mpath LIKE "%.1.%"
    )
)
```

So the question is, how to convert this SQL query into a typeORM query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wrote a quick possible solution. I tested it and it should work fine. Just respond if it doesnt

```js
@Entity()
@Tree("materialized-path")
export class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @ManyToMany((type) => Post, (post) => post.categories)
    posts: Post[];

    @TreeChildren()
    children: Category[];

    @TreeParent()
    parent: Category;

    async getPosts(): Promise<Post[]> {
      const categories = await getConnection().getTreeRepository(Category).findDescendants(this); // gets all children
      categories.push(this); // adds parent

      const ids  = categories.map(cat => cat.id) // get an array of ids

      return await Post.createQueryBuilder('post')
        .distinct(true) // dont get duplicates (posts in two categories)
        .innerJoin('post.categories', 'category', 'category.id IN (:...ids)', {ids}) // get posts where category is in categories array
        .innerJoinAndSelect('post.categories', 'cat') // add all categories to selected post 
        .orderBy('post.id')
        .getMany()
    }
}

@Entity()
export class Post extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   id: number;

   @Column()
   title: string;

   @ManyToMany((type) => Category, (category) => category.posts)
   @JoinTable()
   categories: Category[];
}
```

this method uses querybuilders
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2135#issuecomment-388801132

aswell as the findDescendants function
https://typeorm.io/#/tree-entities

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Work well for parent categories but if i try to get a child category the post assigned to parent categorie is also returned. But we are near the result...

Comment: In fact it's return me every post every time, but maybe i miss something...

Comment: @ZecKa Whoops, it should be an innerJoin. i edited the answer

Comment: It seems work like that, thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I will make more tests to be sure always is right before mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Ok it's work really well, in my case I just add `.innerJoinAndSelect('post.categories', 'cat')` to have also category in selected post like WordPress feed and `orderBy('post.id')`

Comment: And in fact we don't need this line `categories.push(this); // adds parent` `findDescendants` seems contain this

Comment: Can you please provide resource from where I can read how to implement materialised path solution, the documentation for typeorm is not detailed at all and doesn't include schema too, like the mpath variable and it's format etc